# Titanium - iOS Background Service not working

Tags: ios, titanium, background-service

I'm trying to pass a variable to my backgroundService.js and them set the push time through this variable... but it is not working... only work if I manually set the time in milliseconds ...

```
// app.js

var timer = 2000

Ti.App.Properties.setString( 'pushTime', timer )

var service = Ti.App.iOS.registerBackgroundService({
    url:'bg.js'
})


// bg.js

var timer = Ti.App.Properties.getString( 'pushTime' )
Ti.API.info( timer ) 

var notification = Ti.App.iOS.scheduleLocalNotification({
    alertBody:"Passou a bebedeira ja?",
    alertAction:"Ok",
    userInfo:{"hello":"world"},
    sound:"pop.caf",
    badge: 1,
    date:new Date(new Date().getTime() + timer )
})
```

someone knows why when I use `timer` instead `2000` it not work?

Thanks
`3.1.1` `iOS`

Comment: I don't know if I understand you but my code should work... since I change my `timer` to `2000` it make the push...

on Titanium's Doc for this params of notification I get this:

    date : Date
    Date and time for the notification to occur.

Comment: `var timer = Ti.App.Properties.getString('pushTime')`.  Will Javascript automatically cast this to a number??

Comment: yea on `Ti.API.info( timer )` it returns `2000` so it is a number

Comment: That doesn't convince me.  Why would a method called "getString" return a number?  If that's really the case it is no wonder people hate Javascript.  Why don't you try "getInt" and "setInt" instead, just for fun...

Comment: @borrrden: getString() won't return a number value. You can see it here. http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App.Properties-method-getString. The console displays 2000 but it's type is string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DHennrich, `Ti.API.info( timer )` returns 2000 doesn't mean that 2000 is a type of number. Actually it is a string since you're using [setString](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App.Properties-method-setString) method to store the value and retrieve it using `getString()`. When you use `setString` it stores the value as a string and `getString` always returns a string avlue. That's why your code worked when you used 2000 instead of `timer` variable.

From [API Documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App.Properties-method-getString)

> getString( String property, [String default] ) : String
>
> Returns the value of a property as a string data type. Parameters
>
> ```
> property : String
>
> Name of property.
> default : String (optional)
>
> Default value to return if property does not exist.
> ```
>
> Returns
>
> ```
> String
> ```

You can use [setInt](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App.Properties-method-setInt) or [setDouble](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App.Properties-method-setDouble) instead of `setString` to set a property and to retrieve use [getInt](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App.Properties-method-getInt) or [getDouble](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App.Properties-method-getDouble) respectively.

Try to store the value using `Ti.App.Properties.setInt( 'pushTime', timer );`

and you can retrieve the value using

`var timer = Ti.App.Properties.getInt( 'pushTime' );`

I hope it resolved your issue.